# Ember.js hasDirtyAttributes still returns true after save

Tags: javascript, ember.js

```
        this.store.findRecord('meeting',this.get('model.meeting.id')).then(function(meeting) {
            meeting.save();
            console.log(meeting.get('hasDirtyAttributes'));
        });
```

Why does this console log 'true'? Shouldn't this save all the attributes and make it so that none are dirty?

Comment: Can you check the `changedAttributes` of meeting object? And also print the `hasDirtyAttributes` before the save. Also, I don't understand why you need to save immediately after finding a record.

Comment: The essence of your question is in the word "after" in the title.

Answer (score 0):

`model.save()` will sent a request to the server to save the attributes. Until that request is is done `hasDirtyAttributes` will remain `true`.

If you want to be sure that your model is in a saved state you have to wait for the promise to resolve:

```
model.save().then(m => {
  console.log(Ember.get(m, 'hasDirtyAttributes')); // false
});
```